# Android Studio reformat code shortcut not working

Tags: android, shortcut

[image]
This is my keymap config in Android Studio. I used to use `Command+Alt+L` to reformat code after I write a bunch of code and it has been a habit of mine. But this shortcut is no longer working, the `Show Reformat File Dialog`(Alt+Shift+Command+L) works! 
This shortcut is so important to me and I don't want to change it to something else, any idea?

> PS: I have an external keyboard plugged in to my Mac when I'm at home. Last time this happens was when I'm using the external keyboard, so I unplugged the external keyboard, not fixed, and then I restarted Android Studio, not fixed, then I rebooted the system, **worked**. This time I rebooted the system, not fixed, invalidated cache and restarted, still not working. I tried to remove the shortcut and add them back, but I'm not able to add shortcut with Alt and Command both pressed, I can add Alt+L and Command+L, but not Alt+Command+L, so I gave up. Then I changed the keymap setting to something else like `Eclipse`'s and change it back to `Mac OS X 10.5+`, not fixed... The last option I will try now is to uninstall the AS and reinstall it.

Comment: how about change to something else to see if it works? and change it back?

Comment: @Wesely no, I have uninstalled AS, removed all configuration related things and reinstalled, still not working. I have changed it to something else like Command+L, it works, Alt+L works too, but Alt+Command+L doesn't work!